# VB.net default datagridview data

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

So I am have to set some default values in a datagridview, to do so I am using the following code, It is working but I am wondering if I can make the code shorter.

```
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

    'default values for diameterdata
    With DataDiameters
        .Rows.Add(6)
        .Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = "DN20"
        .Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = "21,7"
        .Rows(1).Cells(0).Value = "DN25"
        .Rows(1).Cells(1).Value = "28,5"
        .Rows(2).Cells(0).Value = "DN32"
        .Rows(2).Cells(1).Value = "37,2"
        .Rows(3).Cells(0).Value = "DN40"
        .Rows(3).Cells(1).Value = "43,1"
        .Rows(4).Cells(0).Value = "DN50"
        .Rows(4).Cells(1).Value = "54,4"
        .Rows(5).Cells(0).Value = "DN65"
        .Rows(5).Cells(1).Value = "70,3"
        .Rows(6).Cells(0).Value = "DN80"
        .Rows(6).Cells(1).Value = "82,5"
        .Rows(7).Cells(0).Value = "DN100"
        .Rows(7).Cells(1).Value = "107,1"

    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Did you do your column definitions with the designer? What are your column's name?

Comment: Used the form designer for the collumns, the names are : DNmaat and InnerDiameter

Answer (score 0):

Create a single array with all your elements. Then, loop through your DataGridView cells and set the values contained into the array.

```
Dim arrayItems() As String = {"DN20", "21,7", "DN25", "DN32", "37,2", "DN40", ......}
Dim indexArray As Integer = 0

    For i = 0 To 7
        For j = 0 To 1
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value = arrayItems(indexArray)
            indexArray += 1
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  With DataDiameters
        .Rows.Add({"DN20", 21.7})
          etc
    End With
```

or like this if you want to keep everything as string

```
        With DataDiameters
            .Rows.Add({"DN20", "21,7"})
              etc
        End With
```

You will find easier to play with the gridview if you make your grid with actual code like this

```
 Dim arrayColumn(2) As String
        With DataDiameters
            .Columns.Add("DNmaat", "DN maat")
            .Columns.Add("InnerDiameter", "Inner Diameter")
            .Rows.Add({"DN20", 21.7})
            ' arraycolumn(0)="DN20"
            ' arraycolumn(1)="21,7"
            ' or like this .Rows.Add(arrayColumn)
            'This will let you dynamically change everything at runtime

        End With
```

On the long run, because your grid is not hard coded then you can change everything at runtime.